# Is there any other format battle in Battle Tree?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Unlike the Battle Maison in X/Y that has Triple Battle and Rotation Battle, the Battle Tree only has Single, Double, and Multi Battle in it.

So, where's the other two? Can they be unlocked by some event or something or do they simply not have it?

Comment: Considering the abysmal frame rate even double battles have sometimes, it's likely they were removed so the game wouldn't drop to 5FPS during them

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/187276-pokemon-sun/74614180), [this source](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/battletree.shtml), and personal experience, these are in fact the only modes in the Battle Tree. The only thing that is new to this one is the addition of "[nostalgic characters](http://www.polygon.com/2016/10/27/13434508/pokemon-sun-and-moon-battle-tree-pokemon-league)". Basically allowing you to battle against old characters from previous Pokemon games. E.g. Blue and Red, Cynthia, Wally, and more.

Like the other games, battling will earn you points that you can spend to unlock mostly exclusive items that are frequently used in competitive battling and ev training.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the actual game data for Rotation Battles has been removed from the S/M game code. The logic for Triple battles is still there however, but seeing as Nintendo doesn't do DLC for main series Pokemon games (yet), it's unlikely we'll see them return.